# match the exact word in the same line

Tags: bash, shell

On my script I need to match two words after a specific command executed. 
I need to greep on **karaf-ids** and **DEPLOYED**

I used `grep -F` but it don't match exactly the first word and the second after

```
#helm ls
 NAME                    REVISION        UPDATED                         STATUS          CHART                   NAMESPACE
cantankerous-abalone    1               Mon Sep  3 14:54:53 2018        FAILED          karaf-0.0.215           karaf    
hissing-albatross       1               Mon Sep  3 14:57:14 2018        FAILED          karaf-0.0.215           karaf    
karaf-ids               1               Thu Sep 20 08:18:28 2018        DEPLOYED        karaf-ids-0.0.339       karaf-ids
```

I continue to searching for a solution ...

Comment: add the grep command you have tried to your question please

Comment: @morla: You can't use the `-F` option for this, because you would then need two grep commands in a pipe, and this would then have the consequence that even a DEPLOYED which comes before karaf-ids is matched.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '$1 == "karaf-ids" && $8 == "DEPLOYED"'
```

prints any line which matches these criteria. If that's not what you want, add something like `{ print $3, $4, $5, $6, $7 }` to print just the date, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can Do something like this:

```sh
<the-command-that generated given output > | awk 'BEGIN {printf "%-25s 
%s\n", "NAME", "STATUS"} {if (NR != 1) {printf "%-25s %s\n", $1, $8}}'
```

This will generate the output like this:

```sh
NAME                      STATUS
cantankerous-abalone      FAILED
hissing-albatross         FAILED
karaf-ids                 DEPLOYED
```

Comment: Not my downvote but the `sed` could easily be refactored into the Awk script.  See also [useless use of `sed`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The above-mentioned changes are updated in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this one do the job?

```
grep '^karaf-ids\s.*\sDEPLOYED\s'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to match two words (word1 AND word2) with `grep` you have 2 choices:

If the order of words is known:

```
$ grep word1.*word2 file
```

or if the order is unknown:

```
$ grep word1 file | grep word2
```

In your case they both work.

If you want to use a list of words to search from file (`grep -F`), you can't use `grep`, use awk:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {
    a[$0]
    next
}
{
    for(i in a)
        if($0!~i)
            next
}1' list file
```

Output on your data:

```
karaf-ids               1               Thu Sep 20 08:18:28 2018        DEPLOYED        karaf-ids-0.0.339       karaf-ids
```

All of the solutions will fail for partial matches.

Answer (score 0):

i didn't use first grep because if i write example and examp it will find both. And i dont want that so i use awk

```
 helm ls |  awk "/(^| )$CHART_NAME( |$)/" |grep DEPLOYED
```

with the command below it will find only the line with the $CHART_NAME and DEPLOYED